Angular application, in a AWS S3 Bucket, cannot call extern endpoint
I have uploaded in an AWS S3 Bucket a web application which I created by using Angular 18; the app calls via http (post method) an external mailer service (Sengrid), in order to send messages from a form.
Locally everything works; after uploading the app in the bucket, I tried to send a message from the same form but the message was not sent. By opening the dev console -> network, I read the following error:

405 Method Not Allowed Code: MethodNotAllowed Message: The specified
method is not allowed against this resource. Method: POST
ResourceType: OBJECT RequestId: XXX HostId: XXX

I tried many solutions - including changing the security settings of the bucket, as suggested in other discussion - but nothing works. How can I solve the problem?

That error message is strange. Almost like you are trying to submit the API call to S3 instead of SendGrid. Are you sure the URL of that network request is correct? Based on your comment about the security settings on the bucket, it really sounds like you are trying to do a POST to something (not sure what) in your S3 bucket, which is never going to work.
